# How to match the id of the last two inserted value in the database to a new array containing the same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im in doubt if this question was already asked, if it is ill be glad to see this question mark as duplicate and see the reference because i cant find an identical question that match this.

I have a table and an array variable.

my table is like this:

```
ID | Name
1  | foo
2  | bar
3  | foo
4  | bar
```

my variable is :

```
$myarray = array('foo', 'foo', 'bar');
```

What i want is to get the id of the last two items inserted in the table that match the value of my current array. So the desired result should be like this:

```
$newArray = array(3,3,4);
```

assuming that i have already stored the id in an array from the last two inserted values like this:

```
$idarray[] = mysqli_insert_id();
```

i have a query like now like this but im not getting the right id for each value:

```
    for ($i =0; $i<count($myarray);$i++){
  $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table 
                               WHERE Name = '". $myarray[$i]."' 
                               AND ID = '". idarray[$i]."'");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       $newarray[] = $row['ID'];
    }
}
```

but im not getting the right id. any suggestion?

Comment: should the query be: _SELECT max(ID), Name FROM table WHERE Name = '". $myarray[$i]."'_?

Comment: that one gives me zero value.. the purpose of my new array is i will use it to store in another table as a reference to the first table.

Comment: yeah i get it.. it is similar to that, just few modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i get it:

```
for ($i =0; $i<count($myarray);$i++){

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT max(ID) AS ID 
                             FROM table 
                             WHERE Name = '". $myarray[$i]."'"); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
  $newarray[] = $row['ID']; } 
}
```

it works as i expected.